# Bootstrap 3 same height columns not stacking columns on breakpoints?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height) I've used `display: table` on row and `display: table-cell` on columns.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kA4yg/3/.

it seems to work, but columns do not stack on top of each other (just resize the fiddle demo) under the breakpoint (in this case, under medium-device resolution).

```
<div class="row row-table">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-cell" style="background-color: #8bc34a;">
         <h1>A</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-cell" style="background-color: #795548;">
        <p>b</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-cell" style="background-color: #90a4ae;">
        <p>c</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row.row-table {
    display: table;
}
.row [class*="col-"].col-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Is there any way I can fix this, making it work like the "standard Bootstrap way", i.e. `.col-lg-6` stack under large-device, `.col-md-4` stack under medium-device, and so on?

Comment: you want it to stack ontop of eachother?

Comment: @vico I'd like to make them work just like the work normally, ie if you have two columns with .col-md-6, then they stack on top of each other under md (that is, sm).

Answer (score 0):

easy use @media tag and only apply the table display settings on screen sizes that you want it to look like this and then it will act normally when not.

```
@media only screen and (min-width 1200px) {
.row.row-table {
    display: table;
}
.row [class*="col-"].col-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

}
```

you did have to check the screen sizes css on the exact number on bootstrap

Comment: Sure, but this solution is not flexible. When you use `col-md-* col-cell` you need to write a media query to set up `display: table` when resolution is md (or upper). So on for `col-xs`, `col-lg`, etc...

Comment: @gremo not sure exactly what you mean sorry, can you clarify? maybe this? http://jsfiddle.net/kA4yg/4/

Comment: sorry, I'll try to make an example fiddle.